# create dynamic frames and store them recursively

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, pyspark, cloud, aws-glue

Environment: Python 3.6 pyspark glue aws
I have defined a list with every DF name I have created previously. Then, my next step might be transform this into a dynamic df and stored recursively. Do someone knows if something like this is even possible:

```
for frame in frame_list:
    frame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(frame, glueContext, frame)

    applyformat = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = frame, mappings =
        [("booking_year","string","booking_year","string"),
         ("booking_month","string","booking_month","string"),
         ("total_frequent_customers","string","total_frequent_customers","string"),
         ("period_new_customers","string","period_new_customers","string")],
        transformation_ctx = "applyformat")

    glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
       frame = frame,
       connection_type = "s3",
       connection_options = {"path": "s3://bucket/etl-process/"},
       format = "orc")
```